# Conditional formatting: Need to highlight a cell if it contains partial text from another column

Tags: excel-formula

Here's the issue:
Column A contains a list of search terms (like "plumber near me" and "plumbing jobs near me"), Column B contains a list of negative terms (like "jobs", "hiring", etc.). I want to highlight just the cells in column A that match *any* of the terms in column B. In other words "plumbing **jobs** near me" would highlight red because it contained a negative term. I know how to do it for a single cell, but can't figure out how to do it for all of column B.
Here's what I've used:

```
=COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$B$2&"*")>0
```

and

```
=COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$B$2:$B$100&"*")>0
```

then copied just the formula to the other cells in A. It works for the negative term in B2 - but no matter what I put between the wildcards for column B, including B:B, B2:B100, etc. - it won't grab all the terms in the column.

In other words, I want it to do something like this:

```
A                            B
plumbing company             jobs
plumber near me              hiring
**plumbing jobs**            how to
emergency plumber
**company hiring plumbers**
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array formula `=COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$B$2:$B$100&"*")>0` - it will return an array of outputs rather than one. You're checking if any one of those outputs is true, so try `=SUM(COUNTIF(A2, "*"&$B$2:$B$100&"*"))>0`.

NB I have only tried this in Excel for Office 365, in other versions of office you have to hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter to use an array formula and I don't know if it would work the same way.

Your question implies that you are typing the formula in a column:

> then copied just the formula for the other cells in A

but also that you want to highlight cells red.

To do this in conditional formatting without adding the formula in a column in your spreadsheet, select the range to format and add a new rule (the conditional formatting dropdown is in the home tab). Select 'use a formula to determine which cells to format', then select your desired formatting and use the formula mentioned above, `=SUM(COUNTIF($A2, "*"&$B$2:$B$100&"*"))>0` - editing `$A2` to reflect the *top row* of the range you are formatting (ie if your range to be formatted starts at row 3, change `$A2` to `$A3` in the formula).

Comment: UPDATE: I have deduced that you can't be using Office 365 otherwise your original attempts would have auto-spilled into adjoining cells. You'll need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter if you're entering the formula in the sheet, but I don't think you will if you use the conditional formatting option.

Comment: Actually, it did auto-spill. You are correct on everything, and your formula worked perfectly. THANK YOU!!! (I would upvote your answer, but my reputation score isn't quite there. Apologies!)

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked! did you accept it as the answer? (should be a green tick next to the upvote/downvote arrows) - just so the question shows as solved to the SO website / community.